# create % column in Salesforce summary report

Tags: formula

Have this Summary Report in Salesforce (Lightning) and I want add an extra column for % of the Total.

So I add a “Summary-Level Formula Column” and used this as the formula ….

RowCount/PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount,GrandSummary)

but it only gives me an error that the field “GrandSummary” doesn’t exist.

Business Development Classification  ↑             Record Count

Declined meeting    479

Meeting confirmed   3165

No response 804

Schedule meeting    366

Total   4814

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated …… Thx

Answer (score 0):

Rather than 'GrandSummary', you need to use 'GRAND_SUMMARY'. You're formula should be:

```
RowCount / PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount, GRAND_SUMMARY)
```

The explanation for this is available in this Help article: [Percentage of Grand Total at Summary Level in Reports](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386586&type=1)